# ASP GridView Create link based on value of other column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, gridview

This may sound simple, but I'm quite new to Visual Basic and ASP.net.

What I'm trying to do is create a new column in a ASP:GridView and create a link based on the value of another cell on that row.

Example Row:

```
 Test Name | 123456 | http://www.testdomain.com/123456.pdf
```

123456 being the variable.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HyperLinkField` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
         DataTextField="EntityKey" 
         DataTextFormatString="http://www.testdomain.com/{0}.pdf" 
         DataNavigateUrlFields="EntityKey" 
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.testdomain.com/{0}.pdf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that link in an ItemTemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server"  PostBackUrl= 'http://www.testdomain.com' + '<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
```